# DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error on ubuntu server while running selenium code

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, celery, ubuntu-server

I am trying to run a Selenium code on the Ubuntu server as a background task using celery. I have checked the versions of Chrome and Chromedriver, they are the same. My code works in general, but as it takes 20-25 minutes to run, we have to terminate it manually sometimes. But after it is terminated once, it fails to initialize chrome and gives the following error:

**selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)**

I have to restart the server every time I try to run it again.
I have added the following arguments while initializing chrome to resolve this error:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

As it works in the first go, we can discount the error of chromedriver not being in the correct directory. This process is probably running in the background even while it is terminated. But celery doesn't show any background tasks as running and I can't find any running chrome processes when I use this command: **ps -ef | grep chrome**

What should I do to resolve this issue?